# Why does "Invalid JSON pointer" error occurs when building API docs using Redocly?

Tags: openapi, redoc, redocly

I am trying to build an API doc using OpenAPI specifications. I am using Redocly CLI for building the UI by using this command:

```
redocly build-docs openapi/openapi.yaml
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Found undefined and using theme.openapi options
Prerendering docsError: Invalid JSON pointer: components/schemas/agreement_schema.yaml#/NewAgreement
```

I rechecked my paths but they are correct. [I have created a StackBlitz for the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fmcpvg?file=package.json). That is why I am not sharing any code here.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The paths look like they are missing the first section `specifications/`, they should be relative to the root OpenAPI file. I see it in two places for the `NewAgreement` schema object: in `specifications/components/schemas/agreement_schema.yaml` and also in `specifications/agreement.yaml`